# Unit testing on laravel file downloading location

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, csv, download

I am new to Laravel. I am writing unit testing on laravel for downloading a csv file. When I run the test case, I get `assertResponseStatus` as 200 and I need to open the created csv file and I am unable to find the location of downloaded file. How can I find the downloaded file.

**This is the controller fuction**

```
    public function generateCsv(){

    $list = $this->csvRepo->getDetails();

    $heading = array(
        'heading 1',
        'heading 2',
        'heading 3'
    );

    $this->csvRepo->generateCsv($heading,'csv',$list);
}
```

I need to know the location of downloaded file when run the test case

Comment: please add your code showing downloading the csv

Comment: @hafiz I have edited the question

Comment: look in your public folder

Comment: @Odin Thunder It is not inside project. can you tell me how to set the download path in unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the latest version of Laravel / PHP Unit you are able to use the following:

```
class ExampleFileDownload  extends TestCase
{
public function fileDownloads()
  {
    Storage::fake('file');
    // assuming we wanted to test like this:
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/test', [
        'file' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('testing.jpg')
    ]);

    // Assert the file was stored – I believe this is the line you are looking for
    Storage::disk('file')->assertExists('testing.jpg');

    // Assert a file does not exist...
    Storage::disk('file')->assertMissing('missing.jpg');
  }
}
```

Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: I will try this out and let you know